# MisplacedView, Frame will be different at runtime

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I'm not able to get this warning fixed. When I start the App everything is looking good... I tried to Update frames and everything I found on the Internet.. The Warning came up the first time, after I restarted Xcode..

This is a how my CollectionViewController looks like in the StoryBoard:

[image: error]

Someone knows how to resolve this?

Update:

So it seems like, Its a problem with my TabBar, when I remove it everything works great, Is there some constraints thing with the TabBar?

WithTabBar:

[image: withTabbar]

WithoutTabBar:[image: withoutTabbar]

Comment: The question is very vague. Can you elaborate more on what is the warning it is giving. Most probably it is around misplaced view which means the current position of the view is different than it should be as per constraint.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use **Anchor**.

Answer (score 0):

you have misplaced your views just follow as I have done in the attached GIF. First I will misplace my view which will now show yellow dotted lines as you are seeing.

[image]

Comment: But this is a collectionCellView and I can't Move it

Comment: It doesn't matter

Comment: I removed all content, removed the Cell, added a new one. Still same problem. Now I created a new CollectionViewController, and this one is also not working after I added the TabBar I think its a problem with TabBar